# How do I import contacts from Gmail into Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, email, contacts, gmail

Can contacts from G-mail accounts be imported into Ubuntu One?

Ubuntu one has a contacts sync. I want to sync my Contacts from Ubuntu One w/ Gmail.

From G-mail contacts >> to Ubuntu One contacts

Comment: I think you probably need to export from GMail to a text file (e.g. a .csv file) and then import that file into Ubuntu One. I don't use either so cannot test, hence this is a comment and not an answer. If it works for you then I'll repost as an answer.

Comment: Is it important to you to be able to sync? Or is a one time import okay?

Comment: The service is obsolete

Answer (score 0):

You would need to export your Google Contacts into Evolution and then follow the instructions set out on [**Ubuntu One Exporting Contacts**](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/tutorial/install-and-setup-contacts-sync/)

Answer (score 0):

[Here is where google explains how to export contacts from gmail to a file.](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=24911) After this you can put the file in your Ubuntu One folder.